# Username changes with every new registration in YII framework

Tags: php, yii

I am working on an application built with YII framework. Once the admin  logins, the app redirects to dashboard where in the top right corner we can find the user name as SUPERADMIN. However, when i created a new registration form and adds a user, and on refreshing the dashboard page, instead of superadmin, i am seeing the newly registered user name. how to resolve this? below is the code.

```
dashboard url : http://localhost/myAPP/frontend/web/dashboard
Registration form URL: http://localhost/myApp/frontend/web/site/signup
```

in dashboard using `<?php echo ucfirst(Yii::$app->user->identity->firstname); ?>`
prints the username as SUPERADMIN. however the same code after new user registration showing the new user name. Please help.

Here is my signup code.

```
public function actionSignup()
    {
        $session = Yii::$app->session;  
        $labId = $session->get('labId');               
        if ($labId) {
            if ($session->get('role') == 'super admin') {
                $model = new SignupForm();
                $success = NULL;
                if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
                    if ($user = $model->signup()) {
                        if (Yii::$app->getUser()->login($user)) {
                            $success = "User registered successfully.";
                            $model = new SignupForm();
                            return $this->render('signup', [
                                'model' => $model, 'success' => $success,
                            ]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                return $this->render('signup', [
                    'model' => $model,'success' => $success,
                ]);
            } else {                
                return $this->goBack('../dashboard');
            }                       
        } else {          
            return $this->goBack('site/login');
        }          
    }
```

Comment: You want to display name as superadmin or username ? Nothing is clear. Where is your view code ?

Comment: And, where is you **layout/main.php** ?

Comment: Once I register new user after logged in as Superadmin, If i refresh the dashboard page, instead of Superadmin it is showing newly registered username. Thats the issue.

Comment: Let me clear one thing. Superadmin is registering new user. Or, new user are registering themselves from register.php.? Bcoz, you said **Once I register new user after logged in as Superadmin ...**

Comment: Superadmin is registering new user. I have added signup code. PLease check.

Comment: So, better use **<?php echo ucfirst(Yii::$app->user->identity->getRole()); ?>**. And, declare getRole() in your model. Where, you can fetch role.

Comment: Im displaying role also. Role is displayed as SUPERADMIN, but only the first name is changing to newly registered user's firstname. I have to display Superuser first name in dashboard irrespective of any number of new registrations.

Comment: So, show **firstname()** of your model, from where you are displaying First Name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in this line, `if (Yii::$app->getUser()->login($user))`

Why, I'm saying is. Because, **Superadmin is registering user**. So, there is no need of this line `if (Yii::$app->getUser()->login($user)) {`, because that new user **no need to get login** (as already Superadmin is logged in.) Remove that line and see.

```
if ($user = $model->signup()) {
  $success = "User registered successfully.";
  $model = new SignupForm();
  return $this->render('signup', [
      'model' => $model, 'success' => $success,
  ]);
}
```

Comment: yup ! I just did that and you suggested the same. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad It Worked. Thank You @rgk.